# Interrupt queries execution from being finished

Tags: mysql, sql, configuration, config, mysql-workbench

I have a problem with MySQL server when a user is firing multiple queries to retrieve a big Project (More than 10GB) from a server. the queries stop being executed after a certain time and the connection between the user and the server is being interrupted. Could it be that those queries require more resources or how can I diagnose the problem? and is there any tool like MySQL profiler to find out what causes that as I'm using an older version of Mysql workbench.

This is what my.ini contain:

```
[client]
no-beep
port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port=3306
datadir=F:/Data/Data
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general_log=1
general_log_file="W2K12R2-2018.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="W2K12R2-DE2018-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="W2K12R2-DE2018.err"
server-id=1
max_connections=151
query_cache_size=1M
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=64M
thread_cache_size=16
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=3076M
key_buffer_size=1G
read_buffer_size=512k
read_rnd_buffer_size=512k
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=32M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G
innodb_log_file_size=1100M
innodb_thread_concurrency=9
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=512k
max_allowed_packet=100M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=4161
query_cache_type=0
sort_buffer_size=16M
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
log-warnings
wait_timeout=999999
net_read_timeout = 1000
connect_timeout = 1000
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Im using MySQL.